Why does the mechanical work of getting the conjunctive normal form and disjunctive normal form work?
I'm having a hard time understanding why/how does these processes really work.
All I know is how to get the original expression from the truth table, using the step-by-step work I've been taught, but I really do not know how it works and why does it work.

I had to look this up to discover that POS stands for product-of-sum and SOP stands for sum-of-product in this context, and I taught Boolean algebra to engineering students, although it was many years ago. It's a good policy (people here demand it) to put the complete question in the text box below the title, not just in the title itself, and when you write the question in the text box you should spell out every abbreviation unless you're absolutely sure everyone will know it.

By the way, the mathematical terms are "conjunctive normal form" (CNF) for POS and "disjunctive normal form" (DNF) for SOP, but I can understand why people would use the easier-to-remember terms POS and SOP instead.

So for CNF (that is, POS) is the "mechanical work" like the method shown in this answer to another question?

You can more easily see the disjunctive normal form in action by explicitly adding to the truth table a minterm column (derived from the combination of all the input variables) having $\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $\underline{x^?}$ is $T$}\\
x', & \text{if $\underline{x^?}$ is $F$}
\end{cases}$ before the output of the function. For instance:
$\begin{array}{|cccc|c|}
\hline
\underline{d^?} & \underline{c^?} & \underline{b^?} & minterm & output \\\hline
F & F & F & d'c'b' & T\\\hline
F & F & T & d'c'b & T\\\hline
F & T & F & d'cb' & F\\\hline
F & T & T & d'cb & T\\\hline
T & F & F & dc'b' & F\\\hline
T & F & T & dc'b & F\\\hline
T & T & F & dcb' & T\\\hline
T & T & T & dcb & T\\\hline
\end{array}$
So the 3-argument function $\mathbf{f}(\underline{d^?},\underline{c^?},\underline{b^?})$ mapped by this table will be $T$ only when the minterm is
$d'c'b'$  or  $d'c'b$  or  $d'cb$  or  $dcb'$  or  $dcb$.
Otherwise, $\mathbf{f}$ returns $F$.
Therefore, if you invoke the function $\mathbf{f}$ with the arguments $\mathbf{f}(F,T,T)$, you are calling $\mathbf{f}$ for the minterm $d'cb$, thus the output is $T$. (Notice that $d'cb$ is in the $T$-enumeration of minterms separated by or.)
And if you invoke the function $\mathbf{f}$ with the arguments $\mathbf{f}(T,F,F)$, you are calling $\mathbf{f}$ for the minterm $dc'b'$, thus the output is $F$. (Notice that $dc'b'$ is not in the $T$-enumeration of minterms separated by or.)
The "$T$-enumeration of minterms separated by or" is the disjunctive normal form with minterms, also known as minterm canonical form.
(The conjunctive normal form in its most expanded expression, in contrast, employs maxterms instead of minterms, and the conective and instead of or. So I recommend you study it after having grasped the disjunctive normal form with minterms, and having studied De Morgan's laws.)
